Why is my program returning Nan for some values and not others?
In Algorithms 4th Edition (Sedgewick) there is a question I have been attempting:

I have limited knowledge in maths and way out of practice. I was using this thread as I was having a hard time tracking down the equation to calculate logarithms (my poor search skills) and have implemented the program so far:
public class HelloWorld {
    static final int TAYLOR_ITERS = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(HelloWorld.lg(3));
        System.out.println(Math.log(3));
    }

    public static double lg(int n) {
        double answer = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < TAYLOR_ITERS; i++) {

            double temp = (n - 1);
            int power = i;
            while (power != 1) {
                temp *= (n - 1);
                power--;
            }
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                answer -= ((temp) / i);
            }
            else {
                answer += ((temp) / i);
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static double exercise(int n) {
        double answer = HelloWorld.lg(n) / HelloWorld.lg(2);
        return answer;
    }
}

Firstly, I apologise for any bad code structure/conventions, this is my first time using Java after using C and mostly Python. Without a power function I used a for loop to times temp by itself i-1 times, as when i==2 temp*temp = temp^2, and power then = 1, and the loop won't continue. I then use mod 2 to check whether i is odd or even, as I think that the series provided in the link above alternates between subtraction and addition for even/odd iterations.

Clearly there are some big differences between what Math.log() returns and my own log function, but I can't clearly see what is going wrong

Not really an answer to the exact question, but you're massively overcomplicating the exercise. You get the answer by repeatedly dividing the number by 2 (int division) until you reach 1. The number of divisions performed is the answer.

Ah, and that's because n is the product of base (2) raised to the power of some exponent, right?

@AngusHay debug your app. The only way to get a NaN (a double/float concept): [1] any operation that itself involves a NaN. For example, 5/NaN, is NaN, [2] dividing 0.0 by 0.0. [3] Lots of interactions with infinity, such as infinity - infinity, infinity / infinity and so on. Go through your code step by step to figure out the answer. Anytime infinity or NaN shows up first? That's the place.

Either use a debugger or add traceprints for the relevant variables.  (Learning to debug is part of learning to program.)

The exercise says that your method should return an int, yet your method is declared to return double?

Hi yes I thought that I should truncate to an int, but as other user's have pointed out I have massively misunderstood the question.

First, the reason your code blows up is that the Taylor series for lg only works for values in the range between 0 and 2; above 2 -- which are nearly all the cases you want -- it diverges rapidly, quickly producing numbers larger than can be handled in the floating-point system Java uses. You can fix(?) this by instead computing the log of the reciprocal and negating it, but even there for values not close to one it converges very slowly, taking much more than the 20 iterations you allowed.
But the key is that you misread the assignment. It doesn't ask for the actual log-base-2; it asks for the largest integer not greater than the log-base-2. That's a very different thing; it is simply the position of the highest bit in the binary representation of n, and since Java (like essentially all computers in the last six decades) uses binary integers this is trivial; as commented by Guy just divide by 2 (or equivalently shift-right by 1) until you 'use up' all bits below the one that started out highest. Or slightly less obvious but even more efficient, you can do a binary search for the high bit.
The following code illustrates both (all) methods, and in the process shows how many iterations of Taylor are needed to get even a decent approximation that is still not quite correct for larger values and would need to be fudged.
public class SO78863494ilog2 {

    public static double abs (double x) { return x<0? -x: x; }

    public static double lg_taylor (double x) {
        if( x <= 0 || x > 2 ) throw new RuntimeException("invalid for lg_taylor"); 
        double t=0, p=1; track=0;
        for(int i = 1; abs(p *= x-1)/i>1e-9; i++){ t = i%2==0? t-p/i: t+p/i; track++; }
        // or t += (i%2==0?-1:+1)*p/i or more clever/sneaky (i%2*2-1)*p/i 
        return t;
    }
    public static int track;
    public static double lg_2 = -lg_taylor(1.0/2);
    public static double log2 (int n){ return -lg_taylor(1.0/n)/lg_2; }

    public static int ilog2 (int n){
        if( n <= 0 ) throw new RuntimeException("invalid for ilog2");
        int l=0; while(n>1){ n/=2; l++; } // or n>>=1;
        return l;
    }
    public static int ilog2opt (int n){
        if( n <= 0 ) throw new RuntimeException("invalid for ilog2");
        int l=0, t;
        if( (t=n>>16)>0 ){ n=t; l+=16; }
        if( (t=n>>8) >0 ){ n=t; l+=8;  }
        if( (t=n>>4) >0 ){ n=t; l+=4;  }
        if( (t=n>>2) >0 ){ n=t; l+=2;  }
        if( (t=n>>1) >0 ){ n=t; l+=1;  }
        return l;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] data = {3,4,15,16,63,64,255,256,1023,1024,4095,4096,16383,16384};
        for(int t : data) System.out.printf ("%5d: %f(%d) %d %d%n", t, log2(t), track, ilog2(t), ilog2opt(t));
    }
}

-->
    3: 1.584962(41) 1 1
    4: 2.000000(57) 2 2
   15: 3.906891(222) 3 3
   16: 4.000000(236) 4 4
   63: 5.977280(872) 5 5
   64: 6.000000(885) 6 6
  255: 7.994353(3218) 7 7
  256: 8.000000(3230) 8 8
 1023: 9.998589(11618) 9 9
 1024: 9.999999(11629) 10 10
 4095: 11.999642(41329) 11 11
 4096: 11.999995(41338) 12 12
16383: 13.999891(144821) 13 13
16384: 13.999979(144829) 14 14


Thank you for the code and explanation, I remember now that the taylor series works for a lot of common functions but I forgot that for n > 2 it cycles back and forth for ln.
However, I am a little disgruntled with not understanding what the question was asking, and still can't tell how I was supposed to have known to do this. I can maybe understand that log_2(N) = x, 2^x = N and then you could divide by 2 x amount of times... (I think?) but I don't understand the highest bit you mention, how do the two correlate?
I would like to know how to understand these sorts of questions in the future

Hold on I think I'm seeing why, I might have spent too long a time away from binary representation to remember that nums are binary! If a question asks for base 2, then it'll probably contain binary numbers due to the position of the bits.. right?
3210 -> exponent of 2, the position of the bit
1001
so (2^3 * 1) + (2^0 * 1) = 9, so if N = 9, then the largest int is 8?

@AngusHay, this is based on the decomposition of a number: N = b(0) * 2^0 + b(1) * 2^1 + ... + b(n - 1) * 2^(n - 1).

Actually, I can't interpret the logic of your code (maybe I'm a bit dumb) so I propose another way to achieve the result:
public double lg( int n ) {
     // we determine the accuracy
   int decimalsAmount = 10;
     // value of the increase
   double adicion = 1, 
         answer = 1;
   for( int i = 0; i < decimalsAmount; answer += increase ) {
        // we obtain the result of applying our proposal 
      double aux = pow( 2, answer ); 
        // if the result is greater than the target, we subtract from **answer**, 
        // the value of **increase** previously applied, divide **increase** 
        // by "10", and increase **i** by "1".
      if( aux > n ) {
         answer -= increase;
         increase /= 10;
         i++;
      }
   }
   return answer;
}

